# $100 coupon from Google AdWords - how to put it for the best use?

Tags: google, google-adsense

I keep getting this email with $100 coupon from Google AdWords that doesn't explain much what is it for and what can I do with it. Is it something worthy or as usual? What should I do with it?

Comment: First things first - are you sure it's not spam or a phishing attempt?

Comment: @Farseeker: no, these are legitimate offers from Google.

Comment: Google sends these out quite often, they are simply a plastic card with a coupon code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would use it:

- Set the limit so it won't exceed the $100.
- Use it to split-test the
  click-through rates of the page
  titles and descriptions of your most
  popular or important pages, with the ad title simulating your page title and the ad text as your meta description.
- Use the most successful page titles and meta descriptions on your site.

Answer (score 1):

When you fill in your payment method, you can set it to not automatically withdraw money. At that point you'd have to go in and add funds to it manually. If you do it that way you wont get charged. Only downside is those coupons usually have to be used on new accounts.

Answer (score 0):

By a coincidence I received one of these yesterday too (not by email though, I got an actual printed coupon with a number on it).

If you read the small print, it says that if you go over the advertising budget, then they start charging you for the advertising. Also the coupon is not transferable.

My intention is to put the coupon in the waste paper basket.

Comment: You can limit the spending in Google so that it will not exceed the $100.

Answer (score 0):

as others have said, You can use the coupon and not worry about getting over charged. Having said that, I would open up an adwords acct, and set a low daily spending budget of $2 - $5. You won't get that much in traffic, but use this as a way to learn some about adwords for free. You'll get a bit of traffic, and based how it treats the words you bid on/ what it suggests, you can get a good idea of how Google views your site.

Answer (score 0):

There's only so many things you can do with the coupon: spend it. Most people don't really jump up at the 100$ card because they can't use it. Give out a favor to a friend or someone who has a startup and looking for some free marketing.